# Spark CASE WHEN/When Otherwise that doesn't stop evaluating and accumulates

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

Say I have following table/dataframe:

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | aaa | xxx |
| 2 | 200 | aaa | yyy |
| 3 | 300 | ccc | zzz |

I need to calculate an extra column **CalculatedValue** which could have **one or multiple values** based on other columns' values.

I have tried with a regular CASE WHEN statement like:

```
df_out = (df_source
    .withColumn('CalculatedValue',
        expr("CASE WHEN Col1 = 100 THEN 'AAA111'
              WHEN Col2 = 'aaa' then 'BBB222'
              WHEN Col3 = 'zzz' then 'CCC333'
              END")
    )
```

> Note I'm doing it with expr() because the actual CASE WHEN statement is a very long string built dynamically.

This results in a table/dataframe like this:

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | CalculatedValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | aaa | xxx | AAA111 |
| 2 | 200 | aaa | yyy | BBB222 |
| 3 | 300 | ccc | zzz | CCC333 |

However what I need looks more like this, where the CASE WHEN statement didn't stop evaluating after the first match, and instead evaluated all conditions and accumulated all matches into, say, an array

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | CalculatedValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | aaa | xxx | **[AAA111, BBB222]** |
| 2 | 200 | aaa | yyy | BBB222 |
| 3 | 300 | ccc | zzz | CCC333 |

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just adjusted the case when statement as:

```
df_out = (df_source
.withColumn('CalculatedValue',
    expr("CONCAT(CASE WHEN Col1 = 100 THEN 'AAA111,' ELSE '' END,
          WHEN Col2 = 'aaa' then 'BBB222,' ELSE '' END,
          WHEN Col3 = 'zzz' then 'CCC333,' ELSE '' END)")
)
```

This way I end up with a value like `AAA111,BBB222,` in the example I provided. Then I remove the trailing comma and `explode()` the list into rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, when}
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  (1, 100, "aaa", "xxx"),
  (2, 200, "aaa", "yyy"),
  (3, 300, "ccc", "zzz")
).toDF("Id", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3")

val resDF = df
  .withColumn(
    "CalculatedValue",
    when(
      col("Col1") === 100 && col("Col2") === "aaa" && col("Col3") === "zzz",
      Array("AAA111", "BBB222", "CCC333")
    ).when(
        col("Col1") === 100 && col("Col2") === "aaa" && col(
          "Col3"
        ) =!= "zzz",
        Array("AAA111", "BBB222")
      )
      .when(
        col("Col1") === 100 && col("Col2") =!= "aaa" && col(
          "Col3"
        ) === "zzz",
        Array("AAA111", "CCC333")
      )
      .when(
        col("Col1") =!= 100 && col("Col2") === "aaa" && col(
          "Col3"
        ) === "zzz",
        Array("BBB222", "CCC333")
      )
      .when(
        col("Col1") =!= 100 && col("Col2") =!= "aaa" && col(
          "Col3"
        ) === "zzz",
        Array("CCC333")
      )
      .when(
        col("Col1") === 100 && col("Col2") =!= "aaa" && col(
          "Col3"
        ) =!= "zzz",
        Array("AAA111")
      )
      .when(
        col("Col1") =!= 100 && col("Col2") === "aaa" && col(
          "Col3"
        ) =!= "zzz",
        Array("BBB222")
      )
      .otherwise(Array("unknown"))
  )
resDF.show(false)
/*
+---+----+----+----+----------------+
|Id |Col1|Col2|Col3|CalculatedValue |
+---+----+----+----+----------------+
|1  |100 |aaa |xxx |[AAA111, BBB222]|
|2  |200 |aaa |yyy |[BBB222]        |
|3  |300 |ccc |zzz |[CCC333]        |
+---+----+----+----+----------------+
*/
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time. That doesn't seem it will work for me unfortunately. The actual case-when/when-otherwise statement is very long (dynamically built from a SAP table) and making all the combinations would probably make it insanely complex